# Installing Pinax on Windows

Tags: python, django, web-applications, pinax

Can I install [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) on Windows Environment? 
Is there a easy way? 
Which environment do you recommend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have pinax 0.7rc1 installed and working on windows 7, with no problems.

Check out this video for a great example on how to do this. He uses pinax 0.7beta3 on windows XP.

http://www.vimeo.com/6098872

Here are the steps I followed.

1. download and install python
2. download and install python image library
3. download pinax at http://pinaxproject.com
4. extract the download to some working directory `<pinax-directory>` (maybe c:\pinax ?)
5. make sure you have python in your path (c:\pythonXX)
6. make sure you have the python scripts folder in your path (c:\pythonXX\scripts)
7. open a command prompt
8. `cd` to `<pinax-directory>\scripts` folder
9. run `python pinax-boot.py <pinax-env>` (I used "../pinax-env")
10. wait for pinax-boot process to finish

-- technically pinax is installed and ready to use, but the next steps will get you up and running with pinax social app (any other app will also work fine)

11. cd to your `<pinax-env>\scripts` directory
12. execute the `activate.bat` script
13. execute `python clone_project social <pinax-env>\social`
14. cd to `<pinax-env>\social`
15. execute `python manage.py syncdb`
16. execute `python manage.py runserver`
17. open your browser to the server and you should see your new pinax site

Voila!! Pinax on Windows.

Comment: Great steps Ryan, also its a good practice to create your python environment in a completely new directory, e.g. c:\pinaxenv. Simpler to maange

Comment: In the second half, step 3 works a bit differently for me - "pinax-admin.exe clone_project -l" instead of "python clone_project social..."

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have Python and Django installed, Pinax should install fine.  According to the documentation there is one step that you have to do specifically on Windows however (Under the "Note To Windows Users" heading):

http://pinaxproject.com/docs/0.5.1/install.html

Comment: Actually Pinax document is not very clear about installing on Windows.

Comment: That's because it wasn't possible a few months ago. I made a lengthy attempt, and had to patch several files (including pip's source!) but still failed in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while trying to get the .7 beta working in Windows and ran into a lot of trouble. However, it looks like the 3rd beta release of .7 (the latest beta release) focuses on Windows support. So try that, instead of the 'stable' version - it's close to being released as stable anyway, and is recommended now for use.

In the end though, I switched to Ubuntu and haven't been happier. Python development is much nicer in Linux. It's easier to install many Python packages, I run into fewer configuration issues, and there's better support and documentation available.

Comment: You are right. python development is really much easier and nicer in Linux. But  I have to use windows environment for development.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you meant by recommending a better platform then. Is running Linux in a VM out of the question?

Comment: Yes, One solution is to install linux in VM. Anyway Wahnfrieden, You say that it is not possible to install Pinax (last version) on Windows, that's true?
I don't get the difference between Pinax and Django! Django works on Windows with no problem but Pinax which combines some django modules into one framework doesn't work on Windows. It sounds like we are missing something.

Comment: No, I said that the latest release of Pinax (.7 beta 3) claims to have focused on Windows support, so that version should work for you - though I haven't tried it myself. Pinax has many external dependencies . It's a huge project (you pick and choose what parts you want). A few of the dependencies have trouble installing on Windows, but I think they've worked it out now. "Django modules" can include Python libraries written in C for example, so it's trickier than you'd think.

Comment: Enjoy, Pinax is a great platform. Take a look at social_project, but start out with basic_project and add the things you need, since it's easier to add than to take away. Use social_project as a guide.

Comment: The answer is Yes - you can install and run pinax on windows. I have had zero issues with 0.7rc1.