# unable to install python image library

Tags: python, python-2.7, pinax

I want to install pinax [on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233670/installing-pinax-on-windows), I have to install `PIL` but can't do so

[image]

I'm on windows xp pro 32 bit, sp3, i have python 2.7

**EDIT:**

i don't know if this is caused by `pil` or not, but when i type

```
python scripts/pinax-boot.py ../pinax-env
```

i see

[image]

Comment: did you try restarting your PC and executing the PIL installer afresh with no other programs started but the installer ?

Comment: @joaquin +1 for usage of afresh

Comment: @joaquin no, do i have to restart my pc before installing pil?

Comment: @Will what's afresh? a software? can't find it googling, please give me a link!

Comment: sorry, afresh -> again, cleanly. It is not neccesary to restart your PC to install a library in windows, but I remember getting that warning and it was another program that was accesing the C runtime and was hanging the thing. So yes, try shutting down and up again the computer

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/afresh

Comment: @joaquin i restarted the pc twice and still got the error

Comment: this looks like a different problem. You should try `import Image` to see if PIL is installed as Christoph recomended to you. If yes, you should maybe open a different question. Oh I see you still got the same error...umh! can not help, sorry

Comment: PIL requires a C compiler to function, do you have one installed? I don't remember when Windows started shipping with a C compiler, so if you have an older version you may want to look into this.

Comment: @joaquin `import image` does not work ... therefore PIL is not installed

Comment: @Will i can compile c++, using codeblocks, i believe i have mingw

Comment: It is `import Image` or better `from PIL import Image`, not `import image`.

Comment: PIL does not require a C compiler when using the installer.

Comment: @cgohlke `from PIL import Image` works, now what? should i open a new question or can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [setuptools for windows](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#id2) and it will make your live easier. For example to get PIL you've got to say

```
easy_install pil
```

in your windows shell or

```
easy_install <package_name>
```

for some other package and get the latest version. Good luck!